# Open a specific application settings screen on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I trying to figure out the intent values to open a specific application settings screen on Android, the one that allows you to "Clear Data", "Force Stop", "Uninstall"...

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CommonsWare have answered the question. Here is code you can copy/paste directly and use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS), with a `Uri` of `package:the.app.goes.moo` (replacing the package name with the one you want).

Note that this is new to API Level 9, and it might not work on every device.